# Что за стиль записи в структуре

Tags: c++, winapi, структуры

```
struct tagWNDCLASSEX{
  UINT cbSize; 
  UINT style; 
  WNDPROC WndProc; 
  int cbWndExtra; 
  int cbClsExtra;
  HICON hIcon; 
  HICON hIconMini; 
  HCURSOR hCursor;
  HBRUSH hbrBack; 
  HINSTANCE hInst;
  LPCTSTR lpszClassName; 
  LPCTSTR lpszMenuName; 
}WNDCLASSEX;
```

Так вот я не понимаю,зачем писать WNDCLASSEX после обЪявления структуры,вычитал где то что это создание объекта,то есть ,будто бы мы объявили WNDCLASSEX как tagWNDCLASSEX.Даже если так,то как мы можем уже созданным объектом объявлять новые объекты,типа:

```
WNDCLASSEX wc;
```

Comment: А там, случаем, перед  _struct_ не потерялось _typedef_ ?

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов, 100% из определения убран typedef, мс обычно так определяет свои типы, что в корне меняет суть вопроса

Comment: @goldstar_labs я поэтому и спросил

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это объявление структуры и переменной с этим типом.

Упрощенно:

```
struct StructName
{
    int a,b,c;

} structObj;
```

после чего работаем с объектом

```
structObj.a = 1;
```

или создаем новый объект

```
struct StructName x;
```

Answer (score 8):

Как дополнение - если впереди стоит слово `typedef`, то это объявление

```
typedef struct StructName
{
    int a,b,c;

} Name;
```

объявляет `Name` как алиас для `struct StructName` и позволяет избежать слова `struct` при объявлении переменных - вместо

```
struct StructName x;
```

можно писать просто

```
Name x;
```

Comment: Так зачем Вы написали `struct` в последней строке?

Comment: @EOF При copy-paste забыл delete...